# RDTSC vs. StopWatch

Tags: c#

I programmed my own string matching algorithm, and I want to measure its time accuratly,
to compare it with other algorithms to check if my implementation is better.

I tried (StopWatch), but it gives different time in each run, because of multiple processes running of the Windows OS. I heared about (RDTSC) that can get the number of 
cycles consumed, but I do not know if it gives different cycles number in each excution too ?

Please help me; Can (RDTSC) give an accurate and same measurment of cycles for a C# function, or it is similar to (StopWatch) ? Which is the best way to get cycles number for a C# function alone without the other running processes ? and thanks alot for any help or hint

Answer (score 4):

> it gives different time in each run, because of multiple processes running of the Windows OS.

That is in the nature of all benchmarks.

Good benchmarks offset this by statistical means, i.e. measuring often enough to offset any side-effects from other running programs. *This* is the way to go. As far as precision goes, `StopWatch` is more than enough for benchmarks.

This requires several things (without getting into statistical details, which I’m not too good at either):

1. An individual should last long enough to offset measurement imprecisions introduced by the measuring method (even RDTSC isn’t completely precise), and to offset calling overhead. After all, you want to measure your algorithm, not the time it takes to run the testing loop and invoking your testing method.
2. Enough test runs to have confidence in the result: the more data, the higher the robustness of your statistic.
3. Minimize external influences, in particular systematic bias. That is to say, run all your tests on the same machine under same conditions, otherwise the results cannot be compared. At all.
   Furthermore, if you run multiple runs of your tests (and you should!) interleave the different methods.

Comment: +1 for statistical means. This is probably the best way to go in terms of getting a sense of the average run-time.  You can go further and calculate standard deviations to get a sense of how much variation you have in the majority of the samples taken.

Answer (score 0):

I think to have the most accurate info you should interop with GetThreadTimes():
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683237%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
In the link there is down the signature for use the function in C#.